# Tailwind overflow-x not working with full width

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have list of divs in row. What I want is if screen full then it will simply scroll but its just reducing div size

Its showing like this

[image]

Its not scrolling in full screen

Code is little long so I created Tailwind play link : https://play.tailwindcss.com/IP00al3fVM

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a [Stack Snippet](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/11107541)? Note: Stack Snippets are preferred over links to external repros for reasons explained in [ask].

Answer (score 3):

If you use Tailwind v3 and above, you can replace your first two lines of:

```
<div class="flex justify-between overflow-x-auto w-full">
    <div class="flex overflow-x-auto w-96">
```

with:

```
<div class="flex justify-between overflow-x-hidden w-full">
    <div class="flex w-full overflow-scroll [&>div]:flex-shrink-0">
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/kZNxBqq0R9?layout=horizontal

If you're stuck with using Tailwind v2, you just need to add `flex-shrink-0` to your child elements, replace `w-96` with `w-full` and adjust the other overflow values as shown in the above code.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/ALCxmJsAPq

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want it to display full on the screen. If that's what you want, add a 'w-full' class to your second line. It would then look like this:

```
<div class="flex overflow-x-auto w-full md:w-96">
```